# Adding search parameterers to URL Python Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to make spider to extract data from booking.com with Python Scrapy.

The problem is that my parameters after question mark inside the url gets truncated.

The URL I want to scrape is:

```
https://www.booking.com/hotel/gb/seraphine-london-kensington.en-gb.html?checkin=2019-09-09;checkout=2019-09-12
```

But response URL I get is only:

```
https://www.booking.com/hotel/gb/seraphine-london-kensington.en-gb.html
```

My question is how do I pass these checkin and checkout parameters, so I can get required data?

I know that it's possible to use init function, but I could not make it work.

My code is as follows and I refenced in the command which part disapears.

```
def parse(self, response):

    base_url = "https://www.booking.com"

    for hotel in response.css("h3.sr-hotel__title"):
        link = hotel.css("h3.sr-hotel__title a::attr(href)").get()

####search_url bit gets truncated####
        search_url = "?checkin=2019-09-09;checkout=2019-09-12;dist=0;group_adults=2"
        full_url = base_url + link[1:-1] + search_url


        yield scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.parse_attr)
        pdb.set_trace()

        for details in response.css("h2.hp__hotel-name"):
            yield {
                'hotel_name': details.css("title::text").extract_first(),
                }
```

EDIT:

running the script I get this:

```
2019-07-28 16:48:39 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: 
Redirecting (301) to <GET 
https://www.booking.com/hotel/gb/parkcitykensington.en-gb.html> from <GET 
https://www.booking.com/hotel/gb/parkcitykensington.en-gb.html?checkin=2019- 
09-09;checkout=2019-09-12;dist=0;group_adults=2>
```

Is there a way to disable the middleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the request like this for avoiding the redirect

```
yield scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.parse_attr, meta={
              'dont_redirect': True,
              'handle_httpstatus_list': [301, 302]
        })
```

Comment: I will mark it as an answer, but instead I did put this in settings file, so I don't have to do it for each request. Thank you Arun

Comment: sure, you can add those settings for the common usage.